# Unity doesn't work on VNC server under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, ubuntu-unity

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I find the Unity destkop in vnc4server never works as it did under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Here is my `~/.vnc/xstartup` for vnc4server:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey

/usr/bin/gnome-session &
```

That works fine starting Unity desktop on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, but unfortunately on 14.04 LTS only a gray screen is seen in vncviewer.

I searched a little and find [this article](http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Install-VNC.html) shows the way to start legacy gnome desktop (gnome-fallback) in vnc on 14.04, but what I want is the solution for a normal Unity desktop in vnc.

Has anyone successfully run Unity desktop in a vnc session (vnc4server, or any other vnc server) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Still no for Vnc4Server. But I find Vino + some specific correct graphics driver works. In fact vnc server issue on 14.04 is a known pending bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1251281

Answer (score 1):

This [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/475036/283933) answer by [Blanca Higgins](https://askubuntu.com/users/282622/blanca-higgins) shows the solution.

Install these packages:

```
# apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal
```

Use this `~/.vnc/xstartup` file:

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

Comment: this is not unity